# Put files and folders of nuget package in root folder

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I am trying to package my project file and creating a **nuget** package using something like this: 
**NuGet pack file.csproj -p Configuration=$(ConfigurationName); -NoPackageAnalysis**.

But the problem is it's putting the files/folders relevant to project in **"content"** folder and assemblies in **"lib"** folder but I want files/folder in root and library in **bin** folder something like this .[image]
But right now my folder structure is this : 
[image]

The structure of my nuspec file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata>
        <id>$id$</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <title>$title$</title>
        <authors>abc</authors>
        <owners>abc</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>abc</description>
        <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
        <copyright>Copyright 9999</copyright>
        <tags></tags>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\**" target="bin" />
        <file src="$target$\**\*.*" target=""/>
    </files>  
</package>
```

Even excluding  from my nuspec file results in the same output structure shown in second image. I am using nuget version **4.1.0** and I also tried with earlier version of nuget like **2.8.6**.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this as well, but it is important to understand the difference between the `<files />` collection in `/package` and the `<contentFiles />` collection in `/package/metadata`.

The `<files />` collection tells *the packager* which files to put in your package, in the `lib`, `content` or `tools` directory of your package.

Note: you don't need to use this collection, you can also use [a convention-based working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory).

The `<contentFiles />` collection tells *the package consumer* how to use the files contained in the package.

In your case the .nuspec file should look something like this (not really sure about the `$target$` part though:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata>
        <id>$id$</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <title>$title$</title>
        <authors>abc</authors>
        <owners>abc</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>abc</description>
        <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
        <copyright>Copyright 9999</copyright>
        <tags></tags>
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="bin/**" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\**" target="content\bin" />
        <file src="$target$\**\*.*" target="content"/>
    </files>  
</package>
```

Comment: This answer seemed promising, but it seems that `contentFiles` is actually a different concept: it is just for immutable (uneditable) content files. See emgarten's comment here:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2060

Hence I tried your answer but sadly it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem where I had to put a file in the package root(because an installed add-in app would always look there for the file).

I wanted `my.dll` to be available inside the `packages/My.App.101` folder.
So I did this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata>
        <id>My.App</id>
        <version>101</version>
        <title>title</title>
        <authors>abc</authors>
        <owners>abc</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>abc</description>
        <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
        <copyright></copyright>
        <tags></tags>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="My.App.dll" target="/" />
    </files>  
</package>

target="/"
```

And so this should work for you

```
<files>
    <file src="YourFolder\yourfile.extension" target="bin/" />
    <file src="YourFolder\yourfile.extension" target="bin/anotherfolder/" />
</files> 

target="bin/"
```

Happy Packaging :)